# Audit Record Viewing

Tags: setup-audit-log

Is there a way I can track users access to objects and records?

I need the ability to monitor the following:

Access to record

Comment: are you trying to monitor who has the potential to access a record, or when a user actually does view a record which they have access to?

Comment: When user does view a record.

Answer (score 2):

The platform feature which provides auditing of which users access data in the system is [Event Monitoring](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/salesforce_shield.htm) which is a component of [Salesforce Shield](https://www.salesforce.com/products/platform/products/shield/), a paid add-on.

The tracking which you are looking for in the list below is URI and Lightning.

From the [Event Monitoring Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/event_monitoring):

> Event monitoring provides tracking for lots of types of events,
>   including:
>
> - Logins
> - Logouts
> - URI (web clicks in Salesforce Classic)
> - Lightning (web clicks, performance, and errors in Lightning Experience and the Salesforce mobile app)
> - Visualforce page loads
> - API calls
> - Apex executions
> - Report exports

Answer (score 1):

There's also a workaround outlined here which we are going to implement due to budget constraints: https://www.machinereadablepeople.net/home/2016/10/21/auditing-when-a-salesforce-record-is-viewed

Comment: You have posted two very similar answers in a short amount of time. If these questions are so similar, you should instead nominate one as a duplicate of the other. Furthermore, please review [How not to be a spammer](/help/promotion)